# Laravel duplicate declaration error when compiling assets

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm trying to get Vue.js working in my laravel application but I keep hitting a `Duplicate declaration "app"` error when running `npm run dev`

I've tried running `npm install --require-dev` along with manually installing the babel-loader package

My app.js is as follows

```
require('./bootstrap');
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.component('chat-messages', require('./components/ChatMessages.vue'));
Vue.component('chat-form', require('./components/ChatForm.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

The error I receive when running `npm run dev` is

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
TypeError: D:\Projects\LiveChat\resources\js\app.js: Duplicate declaration 
"app"
  68 |  */
  69 |
> 70 | const app = new Vue({
     |       ^
  71 |     el: '#app'
  72 | });
```

Comment: You don't even need to declare it as a constant. Just remove it all together but my guess is that its declared in bootstrap or one of your components

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by removing the default vue related code at the bottom of the app.js file

Answer (score 0):

Its probably in your component files or in bootstrap.

You can remove it all together though

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
});
```

Comment: I removed the constant but now I get this error 
warn @ app.js:47712 [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <ChatForm>
       <Root>

Comment: Can you tell us what your components look like, just update the question with their contents